# Is it possible to use AWS ELB to distribute load between AWS EKS & GCP GKE Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have create kubernetes clusters on both AWS EKS and Google GKE and I have same application deployed (2048 game) in both of these cluster and both of these have their own individual load balancer which talks to the ingress. Now I have IP address to access the 2048 game in GKE and also have a URL to access same game in AWS EKS.
I would like to know if it possible to create load balancer using AWS ELB which sits on top these two kubernetes cluster load balancers.

I have tried creating load balancer using AWS ELB and but I am not able to setup target group which   talks to GKE cluster load balancer IP address